# Confusion related to this tex

Tags: tables

I have this confusion about what this line in tex does

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Heading 1} & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I am not sure what this `|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|` does?

Answer (score 6):

In your code, `\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}` declares a  tabular environment with 2 columns whose cells are typeset  as `\parbox`es  5 cm wide, and the 3 `|`  mean that the columns are separated by a vertical rule (0.4pt thick by default).

In case the cellsin a row  have unequal heights,they are `top-aligned`. To have centre-aligned cells, you'd choose the `m{5cm}` qualifier, and bottom-aligned would be obtained with `b{5cm}`.

To  change the width of a vertical rule, say for a 1.5 pt thick rule, replace `|` with `!{\vrule width 1.5pt}`.

Finally, if you have many columns  of the same type (say, 8  columns) — A3 paper suggested in that case;-), you can save typing and earn readibility of you code with writing

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{p{5cm}|}}
```

instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
```

This requires loading the `array` package (recommended anyway).